# C++ evaluation order between brace-or-equal initializer and initialization-list?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, operator-precedence

Where I have this struct,

```
struct
AAA
{
    AAA() : bbb(2)
    {
        // ccc ???
    }

    int bbb = 1;
    int ccc = bbb;
};
```

[AFAIK](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members), if there's an initialization-list `:bbb(2)`, the expression `bbb = 1` will be ignored. And then, it's vague to me what `ccc` will become finally.

Which one of *initialization-list* or *brace-or-equal initializer* would be evaluated first? What's the rule between them?

Comment: Why don't you check it?

Comment: @klm123 I don't think specific implementation would guarantee the actual rule.

Comment: @KateGregory Hm, knowing of you I'd be daring to imply that you're wrong, but how would that combine with §12.6.2.9? :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson in a prelease version of VS2013 I got warnings for doing both. However I just checked with the release version and it looks like only the :() one happens and the nonstatic member init does not happen. No substitute for testing :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rule was always that fields are *always* initialised in order of declaration, and C++11 didn't change that. That means `bbb`'s initialiser runs first, then `ccc`'s initialiser runs. It doesn't matter whether either initialiser is specified on the field or as part of the constructor.

Answer (score 12):

The [C++11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) §12.6.2.9 says;

> If a given non-static data member has both a
>   brace-or-equal-initializer and a  mem-initializer, the initialization
>   specified by the mem-initializer is performed,  and the non-static
>   data member’s brace-or-equal-initializer is ignored.
>
> [ Example: Given

```
struct A {
  int i = /∗ some integer expression with side effects ∗/ ; 
  A(int arg) : i(arg) { }
  // ...
};
```

> the A(int) constructor will simply initialize i to the value of arg,
>   and the side  effects in i’s brace-or- equal-initializer will not take
>   place. — end example ]

Since initialization is done in declaration order (§12.6.2.10) with the addition of this rule, the value of `bbb` and `ccc` will both be 2.

Comment: I think the paragraph that immediately follows is more relevant. p9 doesn't actually say anything about the order of initialisation between bbb and ccc, it just says bbb isn't initialised twice.

Comment: @hvd Quoting the question, `Which one of initialization-list or brace-or-equal initializer would be evaluated first?`, although I agree both rules are important.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Ah, I see how you read the question. I thought the OP meant the initialization-list (bbb) or brace-or-equal-initializer (ccc), not the initialization-list (bbb) or brace-or-equal-initializer (bbb, ccc).

Comment: When `bbb=1` is ignored, the order is obvious, `bbb=2` and then `ccc=bbb` so, `ccc=2` -- I think by this paragraph (9) there is not ambiguity for ordering.

Comment: @MM. p9 doesn't say "and then", it's p10 that says that. If you reverse the declarations of bbb and ccc, first ccc=bbb runs (undefined behaviour, in practice sets ccc to an unpredictable value), and only then bbb=2.